# jquery steps : where to put this code

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-steps

```html
<?php
function htm_admin_header()
{
 global $language_adm;
 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr-FR" lang="fr-FR">

<head>


  <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.steps.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script> $(document).ready(function() {
       var form = $("#example-advanced-form").show();
 
form.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
        // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
        if (currentIndex > newIndex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Forbid next action on "Warning" step if the user is to young
        if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age-2").val()) < 18)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
        if (currentIndex < newIndex)
        {
            // To remove error styles
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error").remove();
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error").removeClass("error");
        }
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
    {
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age-2").val()) >= 18)
        {
            form.steps("next");
        }
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3)
        {
            form.steps("previous");
        }
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        alert("Submitted!");
    }
}).validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
    rules: {
        confirm: {
            equalTo: "#password-2"
        }
    }
});
    });</script>
  

  
  
<link href="style/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    

                    </li>
                     <li>
                        <a  href="#"> <strong> 
                        <?php if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {

                            echo $_SESSION['login'];
                        }
                         elseif (isset($_COOKIE['login'])) {
                            echo $_COOKIE['login'];
                        }


                         ?> </strong></a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a class="active-menu"  href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-dashboard "></i>Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    
<?php
```

I'm discovering this plugin, but I don't know how to the integrate on my page. where I have to put the javascript code and below and how ? I have to put in the same file as the HTML or I have to put it in the jquery-steps.js file.

```js
var form = $("#example-advanced-form").show();
 
form.steps({
    headerTag: "h3",
    bodyTag: "fieldset",
    transitionEffect: "slideLeft",
    onStepChanging: function (event, currentIndex, newIndex)
    {
        // Allways allow previous action even if the current form is not valid!
        if (currentIndex > newIndex)
        {
            return true;
        }
        // Forbid next action on "Warning" step if the user is to young
        if (newIndex === 3 && Number($("#age-2").val()) < 18)
        {
            return false;
        }
        // Needed in some cases if the user went back (clean up)
        if (currentIndex < newIndex)
        {
            // To remove error styles
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") label.error").remove();
            form.find(".body:eq(" + newIndex + ") .error").removeClass("error");
        }
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled,:hidden";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onStepChanged: function (event, currentIndex, priorIndex)
    {
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && Number($("#age-2").val()) >= 18)
        {
            form.steps("next");
        }
        // Used to skip the "Warning" step if the user is old enough and wants to the previous step.
        if (currentIndex === 2 && priorIndex === 3)
        {
            form.steps("previous");
        }
    },
    onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        form.validate().settings.ignore = ":disabled";
        return form.valid();
    },
    onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
    {
        alert("Submitted!");
    }
}).validate({
    errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) { element.before(error); },
    rules: {
        confirm: {
            equalTo: "#password-2"
        }
    }
});
```

HTML file

```html
function htm_ajout_livraison(){
 ?>  

        
 <div id="page-wrapper" class="page-wrapper-cls">
    <div id="page-inner">
 
 <form id="example-advanced-form" action="#">
    <h3>Account</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Account Information</legend>
 
        <label for="userName-2">User name *</label>
        <input id="userName-2" name="userName" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="password-2">Password *</label>
        <input id="password-2" name="password" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="confirm-2">Confirm Password *</label>
        <input id="confirm-2" name="confirm" type="text" class="required">
        <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
    </fieldset>
 
    <h3>Profile</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Profile Information</legend>
 
        <label for="name-2">First name *</label>
        <input id="name-2" name="name" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="surname-2">Last name *</label>
        <input id="surname-2" name="surname" type="text" class="required">
        <label for="email-2">Email *</label>
        <input id="email-2" name="email" type="text" class="required email">
        <label for="address-2">Address</label>
        <input id="address-2" name="address" type="text">
        <label for="age-2">Age (The warning step will show up if age is less than 18) *</label>
        <input id="age-2" name="age" type="text" class="required number">
        <p>(*) Mandatory</p>
    </fieldset>
 
    <h3>Warning</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>You are to young</legend>
 
        <p>Please go away ;-)</p>
    </fieldset>
 
    <h3>Finish</h3>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Terms and Conditions</legend>
 
        <input id="acceptTerms-2" name="acceptTerms" type="checkbox" class="required"> <label for="acceptTerms-2">I agree with the Terms and Conditions.</label>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</div>

<?php
 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your code in a `script` tag, and inside `$(document).ready()`, and don't forget to include the plugin, like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugin.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // your code
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes but he doesn't work when i press on the button next,  nothing happens

Comment: That's another question. You asked where to put that code.

Comment: And you have modified your code to suit your markup? For example, you most likely need to modify `$("#example-advanced-form").show();`.

Comment: I put the same as in Example :   <form id="example-advanced-form" action="#">

Comment: What does the console (F12) say?

Comment: thank you, thanks to you I solved the problem. It was enough to add:
<script src = "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"> </ script>

I will take the opportunity to ask you how to make for the "finish" button directs and transmits the data to a PHP page